# Number of non periodic strings

Tags: combinatorics

How many non-periodical strings of length N with letters from a to z exist?

My only idea was something about prime factorization to find the amount of periodical strings of length N.

Comment: Hi -- welcome to math.SE! This is not string theory. Please take note of the tag summaries when choosing tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to [necklace polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_polynomial).

Let $a_{kn}$ count the number of aperiodic strings of $n$ letters from an alphabet of $k$ letters.  For each $d \mid N$, an aperiodic string of length $d$ gives rise to a string of length $N$ with period $d$, so the total number $k^N$ of strings of length $N$ with arbitrary period can be written as

$$
k^N = \sum_{d\mid N}a_{kd}\;.
$$

Then [Möbius inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula) yields

$$
a_{kN} = \sum_{d\mid N}\mu\left(\frac Nd\right)k^d\;.
$$